# Suppose $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$. Does it mean $f$ is also uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

I am just curious if we can use the definition $\forall x, y \in [a,b]$ and $\exists \epsilon > 0$ s.t $|f(x) - f(y)| < \delta$  if $|x-y|<\epsilon$ . Then we just exclude the endpoints. Would that work? or is the statement too obvious and I am just over thinking?
Thanks

Comment: yes, exactly that works. u.c. on $[a,b]$ means its true for all $x,y\in[a,b]$, so its also true for all $x,y\in (a,b)$

Comment: $(a,b) \subset [a,b]$

Comment: The statement is somewhat obvious, but you're not overthinking. What you have here seems like a good amount of thinking to me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would be correct. More generally: if $f$ is a uniformly continuous function from $A(\subset\mathbb{R})$ into $\mathbb R$ and if $B\subset A$, then $f$ is also uniformly continuous on $B$ (by the same argument).